# Get serviceContext from servlet

Tags: java, api, servlets, liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to send a validation email to my users (so they can confirm their new email address) after they perform a certain action.

I'm doing so by calling the following method:

```
UserLocalServiceUtil.sendEmailAddressVerification(..., serviceContext);
```

which obviously requires a `ServiceContext` object to be passed on to work.

`ServiceContextFactory.getInstance()` won't work because it requires a `PortletRequest` object to be passed on, which is not available in a servlet.

Now I read you can instantiate the `serviceContext` object itself and then add the following property to it:

```
ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
serviceContext.setScopeGroupId(groupId);
```

But I can't figure out what in the world `long groupId` stands for. Any help on this matter or any suggestions on other approaches to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupId` is the current site that you're in - if you're implementing a servlet, you won't have it just like the serviceContext.

One of the great sources for this kind of data is [`ThemeDisplay`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/theme/ThemeDisplay.html), you can get it (in the portlet context) through

```
  ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
```

As this is all Liferay specific and tied to the portlet world, the easiest way to get it is to package your current servlet code in a portlet. It doesn't take much and you'll have everything at hand instead of trying to find everything on your own. Is there anything that keeps you from doing this?

Comment: Well this servlet is actually within a portlet, I'm using `PortalDelegateServlet` to publish the servlet within the portal context. Maybe I'm missing something pretty obvious?

Comment: No need to go cross-context here. Just write a standard, classic portlet, e.g. an action- or resource handler and move the code there. If you use the resource-serving phase, this comes closest to a servlet. From that portlet you have all the portal/portlet context readily available and don't need to care getting everything you need. `UserLocalServiceUtil` is also available.

Comment: hey there Olaf, thanks a lot for your help. Quick question thou, and this is where my requirement starts getting a bit weird. The reason I went for a servlet is because it could be accessed from the outside trough a public URL. Now if I go for a _serve resource_, is there a way to access this method trough a public URL? Just as you can with a servlet? Thanks man.

Comment: well, yes you can. The only thing is that - in the portal world - the URL is generated for you by the portal. It might look ugly. However, that shouldn't be anything to keep you from it: You can implement a redirect/url-rewrite in Apache, offering a pretty URL on Apache that is forwarded to an ugly portal URL. Or you can implement FriendlyURLs if you want to stay in the portal world. There are Liferay APIs for this. Apache mod_rewrite is probably the easiest/quickest way though - a bit hackish, but very quick